# Does Google BigQuery command line tool support Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

According Google's documents, the `BigQuery` command line tool is code for Python 2.  So what can i do if I want to use it under Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 is not officially supported, and I don't know of anyone who is using it with bigquery. However you may be able to translate bq.py to something that runs under python 3 by running the [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) script.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but for those still looking, try Pandas; it now has a gbq io function. Have a look here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html.  There are both writer and reader functions.  If you want to dig deeper, have a look at the Pandas source code.